# Java code to get the areas of a particular color in an image

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

Assuming you have an image composed of lines drawn in different directions NE NS SE e.t.c, and with different colors(yellow, blue, black)? Can someone tell me what would be the fastest way to write a java code to be able to get the paths(x,y co-ordintes used to draws the lines) for lines of a particular color. without having to loop through all the pixels of the image.

Comment: are they Strait lines?

Comment: [drawLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) ? Or do you want to extract the lines?

Comment: They are all straight lines, and i want the code to be able to say :  from the following image extract all the lines or in order words for each line give me their paths(x,y coordinated used to draw each line so that a particular line  would have an array of  x,y coordinates)

Comment: I don't think it's possible... Perhaps you can grab some ms by forget some well choosen pixels